# Open Twitch Channel by channel id

Tags: rest, twitch, twitch-api

Is there any way to open Twitch channel by it's ID

Something Like https://twitch.tv/588483962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

You have to convert the ID to a users login.

You can only load up a Twitch Channel in the browser via the users login